# How are elastic bands rated for resistance?

Tags: exercise-equipment

I'm using an elastic band labelled "60 kg". During the exercise, I stretch it from 100% length (where it offers no resistance at all) to maybe 200% length (which does not appear to be its stretch limit since I'm having a slow but steady progress here).

My question is: at what length does it have its nominal 60 kg resistance?

Comment: what brand of resistance band?

Comment: @JohnP Domyos, the black one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very relevant question, but I think the vendors of rubber bands have a different intention by the specification of a weight analogy. 60kg is more considered as a guideline and just means you can use this band for exercises, which you use to do with a 60kg barbell or a load of 60kg in typical machines.

The actual behaviour of an elastic band tends to vary by [temperature](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/stretch-it-how-does-temperature-affect-a-rubber-band/) and age.

If you want to know the length corresponding to a load of 60kg I suggest you measure it yourself in the gym by attaching one end to a pull up bar and let e.g. 3 kettlebells of 20kg hang in the other end.

Comment: +1, this corresponds with what I had found, that each company rates/tests differently.

Comment: I decided to ask this question simply because the "60 kg" band I'm using does not feel anywhere near 60 kg. Judging by the number of repetitions I can do with it, it's more like a pair of 10 kg dumbbells tops. But you are probably right - these ratings come from some sophisticated testing methods not directly applicable to anything practical.